# how can i make my custom html webpage the index page of my wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress, web

I have created a custom html webpage that i wish to use as the homepage or index of my site. However my site is a Word press site. How can i make my custom webpage the index of my Word press site?

Answer (score 0):

It will need to be a php page within your theme folder. You will then need to declare it as a template file by doing the following:

```
<?php 
//Template Name: Homepage Template
get_header() ;
?>
```

Create a new page and assign the Hompeage Template.

It your wordpress reading settings you will to set Your latest posts to a static page and select the page you just created.

Answer (score 0):

You create a template and put it in the theme you are using.  An example name would be page-home.php. 
At the top of the page you put this...like shown here http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

Then you save it and go into the Wordpress console and find the page that you want to change the template and under page attributes on the right hand site you will see Template.  You select "My Custom Page" from the list and save it.

If you don't see page attributes pull down the screen options in the right upper corner and make sure Page Attributes is checked.